# For loop does not execute correctly

Tags: java, string, for-loop, substring

You are given a string S, consisting of N small latin letters 'a' and 'b'. You are also given M queries to process. The queries are as follows:

- C l r ch: all the symbols in the string, starting at the lth, ending
  at the rth become equal to ch;
- S l1 r1 l2 r2: swap two consecutive
  fragments of the string, where the first is denoted by a substring
  starting from l1 ending at r1 and the second is denoted by a
  substring starting at l2 ending at r2;
- R l r: reverse the fragment of
  the string that starts at the lth symbol and ends at the rth one;
- W l    r: output the substring of the string that starts at the lth
  symbol    and ends at the rth one;
- H l1 l2 len: output the Hamming
  distance    between the consecutive substrings that starts at l1 and
  l2    respectively and have the length of len.

Everything is 1-indexed here.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyCode {
static  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);   
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int N=sc.nextInt();
    //sc.nextLine(); 
    String s = sc.next();
    s = s.substring(0, N);
    System.out.println(s); 
//  char[] st=s.toCharArray();
    int M=sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<M;i++){
        String q=sc.next();

        if(q=="W"){
            System.out.println(queryW(s));
        }else if(q=="R"){
            queryR(s);
        }else if(q=="C"){
            queryC(s);
        }else if(q=="H"){
            System.out.println(queryH(s));
        }else if(q=="S"){
            System.out.println(queryS(s));
        }
    }
}

public static String queryW(String s){
   int l=sc.nextInt();
   int r=sc.nextInt();
   return s.substring(l,r);
}

public static void queryR(String s){
    int l=sc.nextInt();
    int r=sc.nextInt();
    s.substring(l,r);                   
    char[] st=s.toCharArray();
for (int i=s.length()-1;i>=0;i--)   //REVERSE THE SUBSTRING
    System.out.print(st[i]);
    }

 public static void queryC(String s){
    int l=sc.nextInt();
    int r=sc.nextInt();
    char ch=sc.next().charAt(0);

    String st=s.substring(l,r);
    char[] n =st.toCharArray();

    for(int i=0;i<n.length;i++){
    n[i]=ch;
    System.out.println(n[i]);                       
    }
 }

 public static int queryH(String s){
    int l1=sc.nextInt();
    int l2=sc.nextInt();
    int len=sc.nextInt();
    String st1=s.substring(l1,len);
    String st2=s.substring(l2,len);

    char[] s1 = st1.toCharArray();
    char[] s2 = st2.toCharArray();

   int shorter = Math.min(s1.length, s2.length);
   int longest = Math.max(s1.length, s2.length);

   int result = 0;
     for (int i=0; i<shorter; i++) {
        if (s1[i] != s2[i]) 
        result++;
       }

      result += longest - shorter;

      return result;
  }

  public static String queryS(String s){
    int l1=sc.nextInt();
    int r1=sc.nextInt();
    int l2=sc.nextInt();
    int r2=sc.nextInt();
    String st1=s.substring(l1,r1);
    String st2=s.substring(l2,r2);
    String temp="";
    while(st1!=st2){
    temp=st1;
    st1=st2;
    st2=temp;
}
return st1.concat(st2); 
}
}
```

This is my code. I am trying to give input as :

```
10
aabbbabbab
10
R 1 5
W 3 8
C 4 4 a
H 2 1 9
S 5 9 10 10
H 1 2 9
C 3 3 b
H 7 8 2
C 2 9 a
S 7 9 10 10
```

But the for loop doesn't work as expected. It accepts only the first 10 values as the input whereas I want the whole to be read. I am making a mistake somewhere, so needed a help.

Comment: Your for loop goes from i = 0 to i<M, where M is the third item in your input. Since the third input is 10, the loop only runs 10 times.

Comment: Can you put breakpoints in your code? It makes debuggin soooooo much easier!

Comment: This needs some more clarity. What exactly are you trying to do? How does your output vary from your expected output? What exactly are you using as your input? Have you used your debugger to step through the code?

Comment: are you comparing strings with "=="???

Comment: I tried string.equals too, then too i was getting wrong answer :'(

Comment: What jipr311 says, you can't use == on strings, unless you want to compare their hashes.

Comment: @Christine if you want to compare hashes you check `string.hashcode()` == will check if they are referenced to the exact same Object.

Comment: == is to compare *references*, not hashes @Christine

Comment: Oh my ! I am a beginner in java, so always used to compare strings with == operator. Read about equals method, got some information. Thanks all ! :-)

Comment: references, hashes, but at any rate, not the string itself :-)